# Hideous performance using Azure mobile services MobileServiceSyncTable

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I have a mobile service sync table that is giving me absolutely HORRENDOUS performance.
The table is declared as:

```
IMobileServiceSyncTable<Myclass> myclassTable;

this.client = new MobileServiceClient("my url here");

var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(“localdb.db”);
store.DefineTable<Myclass>();
this.client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);

this.myclassTable = client.GetSyncTable<Myclass>();
```

Than later in a button handler I’m calling into:

```
this.myclassTable.ToCollectionAsync();
```

The problem is, the performance is horrific. It takes at best minutes and most times just sits there indefinitely.

Is there anything in the above that I’ve done that would explain why performance is so absolutely terrible?

Answer (score 1):

> this.myclassTable.ToCollectionAsync();

For `IMobileServiceSyncTable` table, the above method would execute the `SELECT * FROM [Myclass]` sql statement against your local sqlite db.

> The problem is, the performance is horrific. It takes at best minutes and most times just sits there indefinitely.

AFAIK, when working with offline sync, we may invoke the [pull operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync#a-namehow-sync-worksahow-offline-synchronization-works) for  retrieving a subset of the server data, then insert the retrieved data into the local store table. For `await this.myclassTable.PullAsync()`, it would send request and retrieve the server data with the MaxPageSize in 50, and the client SDK would send another request to confirm whether there has more data and pull them automatically.

In summary, I would recommend you checking with your code to locate the specific code which causes this poor performance. Also, you could leverage adding diagnostic logging, capturing the network traces via [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to troubleshoot with this issue.

Comment: on another problem azure mobile sync tables uses Guid or string as PK, as far as i know. this is performance decrease on clusteredindex