# Azure offline SQL Lite DB store is very slow

Tags: c#, sqlite, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure SDK for Sync local DB with a server in my mobile application. Local DB means it is  **MobileServiceSQLiteStore** from **Microsoft. Windows Azure. Mobile Services. SQLiteStore.** Offline to Online sync is working as expected.I keep doing all the operations in local DB when the app is offline.Surprisingly all the offline crud operations (insertAsync, DeleteAsync, UpdateAsync, LookupAsync) are very slow in the local SQL lite db than online operations. It's supposed to be very speed on local comparing with Online. Anyone have any idea?

This is not duplicate of below question
[Hideous performance using Azure mobile services MobileServiceSyncTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851902/hideous-performance-using-azure-mobile-services-mobileservicesynctable)

I am talking about offline crud operations using the Azure Mobile SDK.I am not talking about offline "Sync" when app is online. I had to use the SDK since the app supports both Offline and Online mode. Theoretically if the app is offline all the offline operations should be equal to the operations we normally do with SQLite

Comment: You may refer to the similar query discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851902/hideous-performance-using-azure-mobile-services-mobileservicesynctable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hideous performance using Azure mobile services MobileServiceSyncTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851902/hideous-performance-using-azure-mobile-services-mobileservicesynctable)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I am talking about offline crud operations using the SDK.I am not talking about offline Sync when app is online.  I had to use the SDK since the app supports both Offline and Online mode. Theoretically if the app is offline all the offline operations should be equal to the operations we do with SQLite